# cfgrid not working after upgrade from Coldfusion 11 to Coldfusion 2018

Tags: coldfusion, cfgrid, coldfusion-2018

After upgrading from CF11 to CF2018, Update 3, none of my editable `cfgrids` are working. When I make an edit and then submit the form, the columns seem to get jumbled. I created the simplest `cfgrid` I could (below) but am still getting the same behavior.

```
<cfif isDefined("form.submitname")> 
  <cfdump var="#form#">
<cfelse>
  <cfform action="test.cfm" method="post" name="testform" id="testformId">
    <cfinput type="Submit" name="submitname" id="submitid">
    <cfgrid name="TestGrid" format="html" selectmode="edit">
      <cfgridcolumn name="A"> 
      <cfgridcolumn name="B">
      <cfgridrow data="john,doe">
      <cfgridrow data="steve,anon">
    </cfgrid>
  </cfform>
</cfif>
```

The grid displays correctly, but what I change 'john' to 'peter' and submit, I get the following dump:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YiKi.png)

As you can see, it thinks 'peter' was entered as both the first and last name, and it also thinks that 'peter' was the original first name.

When I modify any of the fields in the second column, I get the following javascript error in the console:

> TypeError: _dd.values[_de] is undefined.

The error is thrown by `cfgrid.js`

If I submit only a change in the second column, the dump is completely empty.

It seems like the cfgrid is mixing up columns or something.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Get the same on a fresh 2018 install. I would say it's a bug. Best moving away from coldfusions UI stuff. It's been a pain for years. Report a bug here - http://tracker.adobe.com

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried a fresh install on another machine with exactly the same results. If someone is able to run this code without error, please let me know.

Comment: Or if anyone is able to reproduce this error, let me know. If so, I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: I'm also using cf2018 but I could not able to reproduce it. I can successfully run the code with out any issue.

Comment: What platform is your ColdFusion Server instance being hosted on?

Comment: Windows 2016 Server with IIS 10. Also get the same error with Windows 10 Pro and IIS 10

Comment: @whywontitwork What browser are you using?

Comment: same behavior in FF, Chrome, and Edge

Comment: @Kannan.P, what platform are you using?

Comment: @haxtbh, do you mean that you get the same error on a fresh 2018 install? If so, what platform are you using?

Comment: @whywontitwork, I'm using window10 and apache. finally I check both in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Under the hood, `cfgrid` generates an implementation of `Ext.js`. Take a look at the generated JavaScript to see which version and look for your solution in the docs for that version: https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/guides/components/grids.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately the solution here is to move away from ColdFusion's implementation of `<cfgrid>` and roll your own grid-UI or.... wait for a patch from Adobe.

This is definitely a bug in ColdFusion, the error you are seeing is specifically a bug in the function `ColdFusion.Grid.Actions.afterEdit()`

I spent a little bit of time fiddling around with the JS generated with `<cfgrid>` and found that they index into the columns incorrectly

You can override ColdFusion's implementation of `ColdFusion.Grid.Actions.afterEdit()` with your own to create a possible workaround ( I ran on Solaris 11.4 - Apache  - ColdFusion 2018 : Update 3 )

```
<Body>

<cfif isDefined("form.submitname")> 
  <cfdump var="#form#">
<cfelse>
  <cfform action="test.cfm" method="post" name="testform" id="testformId">
    <cfinput type="Submit" name="submitname" id="submitid">
    <cfgrid name="TestGrid" format="html" selectmode="edit">
      <cfgridcolumn name="A"> 
      <cfgridcolumn name="B">
      <cfgridrow data="john,doe">
      <cfgridrow data="steve,anon">
    </cfgrid>
  </cfform>
</cfif>

<script>

    ColdFusion.Grid.Actions.afterEdit = function(_d8, _d9, _da) {
        var _db = _d9.value;
        if (_db == this.editOldValue) {
            return;
        }
        if (this.insertInProgress == false && this.onChangeFunction) {
            this.onChangeHandler("U", this.selectedRow, _d9);
        } else {
            if (!this.dynamic) {
                rowidx = _d9.rowIdx;
                if (!rowidx && rowidx != 0) {
                    rowidx = _d9.row;
                }
                var _dc = ColdFusion.Grid.computeActualRow_editField(this.editFieldState, _d9.record.data.CFGRIDROWINDEX);
                var _dd = this.editFieldState[_dc - 1];
                var _de = _d9.colIdx;
                if (!_de && _de != 0) {
                    _de = _d9.column;
                }
                _de = _de + 1;
                if (_dd) {
                    if (this.multiRowSelection === true && this.insertInProgress == true) {
                        _de = _de - 1;
                    }
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Subtracted 1 from column index to correctly index array 
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------

                    _dd.values[_de -1][1] = _db;
                } else {
                    var _df = this.grid.getStore().getById(_d9.record.data.CFGRIDROWINDEX);
                    _dd = ColdFusion.Grid.Actions.initEditState(this, "U", _df, _dc);
                    var _e0 = this.editOldValue + "";
                    if (_d9.column.type == "date") {
                        if (_e0 && typeof _e0 == "string") {
                            _e0 = new Date(_e0);
                        }
                        var _e1 = "F, j Y H:i:s";
                        if (_d9.column && _d9.column.format) {
                            _e1 = _d9.column.format;
                        }
                        _dd.values[_de][1] = Ext.Date.format(_db, _e1);
                        _dd.values[_de][0] = _e0 ? Ext.Date.format(_e0, _e1) : _e0;
                    } else {
   //-------------------------------------------------------------------
  //Subtracted 1 from column index to correctly index array 
  //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                        _dd.values[_de -1][0] = _e0;
                        _dd.values[_de -1][1] = _db;
                    }
                }
                ColdFusion.Grid.Actions.computeEditField(this);
            }
        }
        this.editOldValue = null;
        this.fireSelectionChangeEvent();
    }
    ;
</script>

</BODY>
```

There are definitely a ton of other bugs plaguing this tag ... and its definitely worth noting that Lucee ( opensource ColdFusion engine) DOES NOT support this [tag](https://docs.lucee.org/reference/tags/grid.html)

Comment: Agreed. Since they also deprecated/removed some of the UI stuff in 2018, it is likely this won't be the only upgrade issue you'll run into. Though it's probably not what you want to hear, switching to another (working) library now will ultimately save a lot of wasted time spent on chasing down these bugs.

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful. And thanks for the workaround. I think we will start exploring our options. Any suggestions for a different grid-ui? I submitted a bug report to Adobe, by the way: https://tracker.adobe.com/#/view/CF-4204128

Comment: Might be worthwhile taking a look as mentioned in the comments at Ext.js grid , or possibly taking this approach ( although at preliminary glance I don't see them implementing edit functionality) https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way/blob/master/chapters/cfgrid/index.md